# NaN loss when training regression network

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, theano, loss-function

I have a data matrix in "one-hot encoding" (all ones and zeros) with 260,000 rows and 35 columns.  I am using Keras to train a simple neural network to predict a continuous variable.  The code to make the network is the following:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1024, input_shape=(n_train,)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))

model.add(Dense(512))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))

model.add(Dense(256))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(1))

sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, nesterov=True);
#rms = RMSprop()
#model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=rms, metrics=['accuracy'])
model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer=sgd)
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=32, nb_epoch=3, verbose=1, validation_data=(X_test,Y_test), callbacks=[EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=4)] )
```

However, during the training process, I see the loss decrease nicely, but during the middle of the second epoch, it goes to nan:

```
Train on 260000 samples, validate on 64905 samples
Epoch 1/3
260000/260000 [==============================] - 254s - loss: 16.2775 - val_loss:
 13.4925
Epoch 2/3
 88448/260000 [=========>....................] - ETA: 161s - loss: nan
```

I tried using `RMSProp` instead of `SGD`, I tried `tanh` instead of `relu`, I tried with and without dropout, all to no avail.  I tried with a smaller model, i.e. with only one hidden layer, and same issue (it becomes nan at a different point).  However, it does work with less features, i.e. if there are only 5 columns, and gives quite good predictions. It seems to be there is some kind of overflow, but I can't imagine why--the loss is not unreasonably large at all.

Python version 2.7.11, running on a linux machine, CPU only.  I tested it with the latest version of Theano, and I also get Nans, so I tried going to Theano 0.8.2 and have the same problem.  With the latest version of Keras has the same problem, and also with the 0.3.2 version.

Comment: Try loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam' with a single hidden layer - still nans?

Comment: @1'' When using the above model with Adam optimizer, I get nans.  With just one layer, it does not give nans during the three epochs of training.

Comment: for future readers, here is a relevant keras thread. https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2134 
I have some success by combining all of the suggestions mentioned here. e.g. adding batchnorm, varying the learning rate, optimizer, adding clip_by_value, clip_by_global_norm, finally, combing through the code multiple times for bugs also helps, e.g. missing batch norm layer following one conv layer.  :)

Answer (score 179, accepted):

Regression with neural networks is hard to get working because the output is unbounded, so you are especially prone to the [exploding gradients problem](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap5.html) (the likely cause of the nans).

Historically, one key solution to exploding gradients was to reduce the learning rate, but with the advent of per-parameter adaptive learning rate algorithms like Adam, you no longer need to set a learning rate to get good performance.  There is very little reason to use SGD with momentum anymore unless you're a neural network fiend and know how to tune the learning schedule.

Here are some things you could potentially try:

1. Normalize your outputs by [quantile normalizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_normalization) or [z scoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score).  To be rigorous, compute this transformation on the training data, not on the entire dataset.  For example, with quantile normalization, if an example is in the 60th percentile of the training set, it gets a value of 0.6.  (You can also shift the quantile normalized values down by 0.5 so that the 0th percentile is -0.5 and the 100th percentile is +0.5).
2. Add regularization, either by increasing the dropout rate or adding L1 and L2 penalties to the weights.  L1 regularization is analogous to feature selection, and since you said that reducing the number of features to 5 gives good performance, L1 may also.
3. If these still don't help, reduce the size of your network.  This is not always the best idea since it can harm performance, but in your case you have a large number of first-layer neurons (1024) relative to input features (35) so it may help.
4. Increase the batch size from 32 to 128.  128 is fairly standard and could potentially increase the stability of the optimization.

Comment: Regarding 1. Why not normalizing the entire output set? Also, can I use scaling instead?

Comment: @Eran If you use the entire dataset (train + test) when deciding how to normalize, you're indirectly incorporating information about the test set into the training set, which is a form of train-test contamination.  As long as you're only using the training set when deciding how to normalize, though, you can use scaling or any other kind of normalization that gives good performance.

Comment: Checking the batch size and find that it is too small (16), increasing the batch size to 128 works!

Comment: My rule of thumb with regard to batch size is that it should be as big as memory permits but at most 1% of the number of observations. 1% will give you 100 random batches which means that you still have the stochastic part of stochastic gradient descent.

Comment: as far as I know, using 'adam' optimizer you do not need give lr manually as param

Comment: why would increasing batch size solve the nan problem?

Comment: I had the same problem (for a deep CNN autoencoder model) and increasing the batch size from 32 to 128 indeed solved nan problem.

Comment: "[A batch size of] 128 is fairly standard" -- citation needed, especially given LeCun's popularized statement: [*"Friends don't let friends use minibatches larger than 32."*](https://twitter.com/ylecun/status/989610208497360896?lang=en)

Answer (score 66):

The answer by 1" is quite good. However, all of the fixes seems to fix the issue indirectly rather than directly. I would recommend using gradient clipping, which will clip any gradients that are above a certain value.

In Keras you can use `clipnorm=1` (see https://keras.io/optimizers/) to simply clip all gradients with a norm above 1.

Comment: Fair point!  This is a totally legitimate strategy that's often used with recurrent neural networks, for example.  However, before resorting to this it's always good to check that something simple hasn't gone wrong with the optimization.

Comment: The same keras link suggests that gradient clipping is no longer supported. Is there an analogous solution?

Comment: Does this work for all optimizers? And is it always a good idea to set to 1.0?

Comment: Yep, it should work across optimizers. If your optimization problem is sufficiently simple/stable, then this is not needed and may slow training a bit w/o yielding any benefit.

Comment: In my experience, you can still have exploding gradients if you don't scale your data whether you have clipnorm working for you or not. Without seeing the input data in the form it takes at the Input(...) step, it's hard to know if this is the solution or not. I'm not saying this is wrong, but I can imagine someone assume that if they're getting nan losses that this will solve their problem when it may not.

Answer (score 57):

I faced the same problem before. I search and find this question and answers. All those tricks mentioned above are important for training a deep neural network. I tried them all, but still got NAN.

I also find this question here. https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2134. 
I cited the author's summary as follows：

> I wanted to point this out so that it's archived for others who may
>   experience this problem in future. I was running into my loss function
>   suddenly returning a nan after it go so far into the training process.
>   I checked the relus, the optimizer, the loss function, my dropout in
>   accordance with the relus, the size of my network and the shape of the
>   network. I was still getting loss that eventually turned into a nan
>   and I was getting quite fustrated.
>
> Then it dawned on me. I may have some bad input. It turns out, one of
>   the images that I was handing to my CNN (and doing mean normalization
>   on) was nothing but 0's. I wasn't checking for this case when I
>   subtracted the mean and normalized by the std deviation and thus I
>   ended up with an exemplar matrix which was nothing but nan's. Once I
>   fixed my normalization function, my network now trains perfectly.

I agree with the above viewpoint: the input is sensitive for your network. **In my case,** I use the log value of density estimation as an input. The absolute value could be very huge, which may result in NaN after several steps of gradients. I think the input check is necessary. First, you should make sure the input **does not** include **-inf or inf**, or some extremely large numbers in absolute value.

Comment: I had the same issue as you. While checking my data, I found multiple places with inf data points. Taking those out solved the problem.

Comment: This resolved the problem for me, I had multiple NaNs in my embedding matrix :) Thanks.

Comment: I scale the input images (png) from 0-255 (uint8) to 0.-1.(float32), never would I have thought the input was the culprit.... adding a tf.clip_by_value prior passing the input to the net for training seem to resolved my 9 month long debug journey...

Comment: Also, note that `np.isnan(np.inf) == False`.  To ensure none of your examples contain NaNs or Infs, you can do something like `assert np.all(np.isfinite(X))`.  (This has caught me out several times:  I believed my data was fine because I was checking for NaNs.  But I'd forgotten that `np.isnan` doesn't notice Infs!)

Comment: @pangyuteng could you give some detail as to what was causing the error in your case? If the input is always scaled to 0-1 by /255, I don't see how that would cause NaNs...

Comment: @momo agreed.  Looking at my comment in 2019, the 2021 me disagree with that statement.  I think the gist of it is to not trust the input, and always check for nan, out of range values, prior feeding the values to your model. that keras issue#2134 is a good read if you are getting nan issues. good luck!

Comment: Exactly the issue I was facing: sometimes, we just miss the obvious. Amazing what a simple `dropna()` could achieve.

Comment: Thanks, man. I feel so stupid for not having thought of this myself. I had a method creating batches with (kind of) augmented data, which was occasionally returning NaN values, due to an (extremely trivial) error that was causing it to populate the wrong row in a numpy array pre-initialized with NaNs ...

Answer (score 24):

I faced the same problem with using LSTM, the problem is my data has some nan value after standardization, therefore, we should check the input model data after the standarization if you see you will have nan value:

```
print(np.any(np.isnan(X_test)))
print(np.any(np.isnan(y_test)))
```

you can solve this by adding a small value(0.000001) to Std like this,

```
def standardize(train, test):


    mean = np.mean(train, axis=0)
    std = np.std(train, axis=0)+0.000001

    X_train = (train - mean) / std
    X_test = (test - mean) /std
    return X_train, X_test
```

Answer (score 19):

To sum up the different solutions mentioned here and from this [github](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2134) discussion, which would depend of course on your particular situation:

- Add regularization to add l1 or l2 penalties to the weights. Otherwise, try a smaller l2 reg. i.e l2(0.001), or remove it if already exists.
- Try a smaller Dropout rate.
- Clip the gradients to prevent their explosion. For instance in Keras you could use clipnorm=1. or clipvalue=1. as parameters for your optimizer.
- Check validity of inputs (no NaNs or sometimes 0s). i.e df.isnull().any()
- Replace optimizer with Adam which is easier to handle. Sometimes also replacing sgd with rmsprop would help.
- Use RMSProp with heavy regularization to prevent gradient explosion.
- Try normalizing your data, or inspect your normalization process for any bad values introduced.
- Verify that you are using the right activation function (e.g. using a softmax instead of sigmoid for multiple class classification).
- Try to increase the batch size (e.g. 32 to 64 or 128) to increase the stability of your optimization.
- Try decreasing your learning rate.
- Check the size of your last batch which may be different from the batch size.

Comment: be carefull: with too large batch_size you can [stuck in local minimum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49924566/15893581)

Comment: Why would having a last batch size of different size be a problem?

Comment: Another cause is using mixed precession, which will force the use of float16 vs float32, I also had the issue of NaN with mean_absolute_error, tried all the solutions above and then found out I was still using mixed_precision due to a copy of a Jupyter notebook.

Comment: Removing L2 regularization solved my NaN validation loss problem. But why?

Answer (score 16):

I faced a very similar problem, and this is how I got it to run.

The first thing you can try is changing your activation to LeakyReLU instead of using Relu or Tanh. The reason is that often, many of the nodes within your layers have an activation of zero, and backpropogation doesn't update the weights for these nodes because their gradient is also zero. This is also called the 'dying ReLU' problem (you can read more about it here: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/5706/what-is-the-dying-relu-problem-in-neural-networks).

To do this, you can import the LeakyReLU activation using:

```
from keras.layers.advanced_activations import LeakyReLU
```

and incorporate it within your layers like this:

```
model.add(Dense(800,input_shape=(num_inputs,)))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
```

Additionally, it is possible that the output feature (the continuous variable you are trying to predict) is an imbalanced data set and has too many 0s. One way to fix this issue is to use smoothing. You can do this by adding 1 to the numerator of all your values in this column and dividing each of the values in this column by 1/(average of all the values in this column)

This essentially shifts all the values from 0 to a value greater than 0 (which may still be very small). This prevents the curve from predicting 0s and minimizing the loss (eventually making it NaN). Smaller values are more greatly impacted than larger values, but on the whole, the average of the data set remains the same.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem, I was using Keras for a Multivariate regression problem. What I later realised was that some values in my dataset were nan and that led to a nan loss.
I used the command:

`df=df.dropna()`

And it resolved my issue.

Comment: True, there shouldn't be any NaN values in the data we feed to the NeuralNet.

Answer (score 3):

I tried every suggestion on this page and many others to no avail. We were importing csv files with pandas, then using `keras Tokenizer` with text input to create vocabularies and word vector matrices. After noticing some CSV files led to nan while others worked, suddenly we looked at the encoding of the files and realized that **ascii** files were NOT working with keras, leading to `nan` loss and accuracy of `0.0000e+00`; however, **utf-8 and utf-16 files *were* working**! Breakthrough.

If you're performing textual analysis and getting `nan` loss after trying these suggestions, use `file -i {input}` (linux) or `file -I {input}` (osx) to discover your file type. If you have `ISO-8859-1` or `us-ascii`, try converting to `utf-8` or `utf-16le`. Haven't tried the latter but I'd imagine it would work as well. Hopefully this helps someone very very frustrated!

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the loss as nan in the very first epoch, as soon as the training starts. Solution as simple as removing the nas from the input data worked for me (df.dropna())

I hope this helps someone encountering similar problem

Comment: How did you remove the nans from the first epoch? I'm having nans before I start training

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with my RNN with keras LSTM layers, so I tried each solution from above. I had already scaled my data (with `sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler`), there were no `NaN` values in my data after scaling. Solutions like using LeakyRelU or changing learning rate didn't help.

So I decided to change the scaler from `MinMaxScaler` to `StandardScaler`, even though I had no `NaN` values and I found it odd but it worked!

Answer (score 3):

In my case the issue was that I copy-pasted my previous work for binary classification and used `sigmoid` activation on the output layer instead of `softmax` (the new network was about multiclass classification).

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem using keras. Loss turned into NAN after the second batch was input.

I tried to:

1. Use softmax as activation of output dense layer
2. Drop nan in the input
3. Normalize the input

However, that didn't work. So, then I tried to:

4. Decrease the learning rate

Problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

Try to check your data if there are NAN values. Removing NAN values solve the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue when one of my training data entries contained a nan

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue with my logloss, MAE and others being all NA's. I looked into the data and found, I had few features with NA's in them. I imputed NA's with approximate values and was able to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my keras CNN, as others I tried all above solutions: decrease learning rate, drop nullity from train data, normalize data, add dropout layer and ...
but there couldn't solve nan problem, I tried change activation function in classifier (last) layer from sigmoid to softmax. It worked!
try changing activation function of last layer to softmax!

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same thing when I tried creating a bounding box regressor. 
My neural net had larger layer than yours . I  increased the dropout value and got suitable results.

Answer (score 0):

Was getting NaN for my classification network.
Answering here as it might help someone.

Had made a blunder -

Number of classes in training labels was 5. i.e. from 0 to 4.

In the last dense layer of classification had 4 nodes which means 4 classes which is the issue.

Chaging the number of nodes in the last layer of network to 5 solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I tried changing my activations from Sigmoid to Softmax and from RelU to LeakyRelU and the problem was resolved. So I guess as long as there is no NaN in the input to begin with, and you have tried lowering your learning rate, the viable solution is to play with your activations!

Answer (score 0):

My situation:

```
Train Loss: nan, Train Accuracy: 0.0, Validation Loss: nan, Validation Accuracy: 0.0
```

later I found out it was because of my labels are `1, 2, 3, 4` not start with 0.
So I relabel them, use `0, 1, 2, 3` instead of `1, 2, 3, 4` as labels.
Problem solved!

Hope my answer helps!

Answer (score 0):

In keras, class labels begins from 0. If, for example, you have 7 classes, therefore either begin labeling them from 0 through 6 and feed the last dense layer (with the softmax activation function) with units=7. Or if you should label your data from 1 through 7, in this case, you must set units=8 (in the last dense layer).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was getting `nan` values for binary classification then I changed the loss function to 'binary cross entropy' from categorical cross-entropy and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, it seems to be a **dying gradient** NOT exploding.

- neuron dies when its input is negative for all training instances.

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65964472/how-can-i-get-rid-of-nan-on-the-predictions-and-loss-lstm-with-keras?noredirect=1&lq=1) 'adam' optimizer helped against NaNs.
But concerning your situation - be sure, you have **scaled dataset** & loss='**mean_squared_error**' (as opposed to yours)

```
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = keras.losses.mean_squared_error, metrics=keras.metrics.mean_absolute_error)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error may occur when your data have problems like:

> Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
> In these cases, you can solve it by removing NaN values like :

```
`df = df.dropna()`
```

or any other `fillna()` methods

**Note**: These methods work for pandas' data frames only.

Answer (score 0):

Remove rows containing with nan value or replace the nan value with some value from datasets or dataframe. it will solve the error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that there was some nan values in the dataframe. Just remove those nan values using fillnan().

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score -2):

I got the same issue. Successfully you can use keras for regression. **Convert All your data into Rounded number** that solved my issue. **Eg. 23.43 to 23**

Answer (score -3):

I had the same problem. Examining the data, I realized that an error had occurred during data acquisition.

Comment: More of a comment