# Choosing number of Steps per Epoch

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

If I want to train a model with train_generator, is there a significant difference between choosing

- 10 Epochs with 500 Steps each

and

- 100 Epochs with 50 Steps each

Currently I am training for 10 epochs, because each epoch takes a long time, but any graph showing improvement looks very "jumpy" because I only have 10 datapoints. I figure I can get a smoother graph if I use 100 Epochs, but I want to know first if there is any downside to this

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Based on what you said it sounds like you need a larger `batch_size`, and of course there are implications with that which could impact the steps_per_epoch and number of epochs.

**To solve for jumping-around**

- **A larger batch size** will give you a better gradient and will help to prevent jumping around
- You may also want to consider a smaller learning rate, or a learning rate scheduler (or decay) to allow the network to "settle in" as it trains

**Implications of a larger batch-size**

- Too large of a batch_size can produce memory problems, especially if you are using a GPU. Once you exceed the limit, dial it back until it works. This will help you find the max batch-size that your system can work with.
- Too large of a batch size can get you stuck in a local minima, so if your training get stuck, I would reduce it some. Imagine here you are over-correcting the *jumping-around* and it's not jumping around enough to further minimize the loss function.

**When to reduce epochs**

- If your train error is very low, yet your test/validation is very high, then you have over-fit the model with too many epochs.
- The best way to find the right balance is to use early-stopping with a validation test set. Here you can specify when to stop training, and save the weights for the network that gives you the best validation loss. (I highly recommend using this always)

**When to adjust steps-per-epoch**

- Traditionally, the steps per epoch is calculated as train_length // batch_size, since this will use all of the data points, one batch size worth at a time.
- If you are augmenting the data, then you can stretch this a tad (sometimes I multiply that function above by 2 or 3 etc. But, if it's already training for too long, then I would just stick with the traditional approach.

Comment: Yes I have used a relatively small batch size because of OOM errors. I will try to inch towards the maximum.

As for your last point, are you saying that I should have to many steps that I iterate over every sample at least once per epoch? I do use data augmentation, but not during training. I have augmented my training and validation data by *10, and am using this new larger set as my training and validation set. Is this approach worse than using my original sets and then augmenting "live" during training?

Comment: I'm getting a little confused so I'll just lay out how I would use data augmentation along with validation. Augment your train only, your validation and test data are left unaltered. Calculate steps_per_epoch as (train_lenth//batchsize) multiplied by any number >=1 if desired. Create a validation set of reasonable size but this should be separate from your train and test sets.

Comment: What I was asking is: do you use data augmentation by creating an ImageDataGenerator and passing it to your fit function, or did you already augment your training data beforehand and save it on your disk, for example by using a script?

Comment: Ah, I augment live at least initially. This can however create a bottleneck in the training so augmenting and saving can also speed up the training.

Comment: I have similar questions about using Keras' ImageDataGenerator `train_gen = ImageDataGenerator(width_shift_range=0.3,height_shift_range=0.3,zoom_range=0.4)` and passing it into Keras' fit method (e.g. `model.fit(train_gen.flow(train_data,train_labels,batch_size=batch_size),steps_per_epoch=int(len(train_data)/batch_size),epochs=100)`).  Say `len(train_data) = 1000` and `batch_size=20`.  The `train_gen.flow(...)` call will generate augmented images so that in effect to the system it appears that I have more than 1000 train images.  Can/should I set `steps_per_epoch` to a much larger size?

Comment: @ChrisFarr , why do you say >= 1 ? Is it necessary? Can I set number of steps to be less than train_length/batch_size? Can you answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55377309/implications-of-setting-lower-or-higher-steps-during-training-in-keras

Comment: So a larger batch size means less steps per epoch and less steps per epoch means faster training. That means the larger the batch size the faster the training, which actually is not in par with what I've been reading about batch size in general.

Comment: "So a larger batch size means less steps per epoch and less steps per epoch means faster training" No, not faster training, the larger the batch-size, the faster it loops through all the data, but that doesn't mean it will train faster.

Comment: what if I have `train_length / batch_size ~ 1`? Is it advisable to ramp this up to, say, 10 or 100 steps per epoch, should I just do 1 step, or should I decrease batch_size?

Answer (score 6):

Steps per epoch does not connect to epochs.

Naturally what you want if to 1 epoch your generator pass through all of your training data one time. To achieve this you should provide steps per epoch equal to number of batches like this:

```python
steps_per_epoch = int( np.ceil(x_train.shape[0] / batch_size) )
```

as from above equation the largest the `batch_size`, the lower the `steps_per_epoch`.

Next you will choose epoch based on chosen validation. (choose what you think best)

Comment: Do you know what happens if the above equality is not followed? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55377309/implications-of-setting-lower-or-higher-steps-during-training-in-keras

Comment: Does it matter if `floor` is used instead of `ceil`? How will it work in the `model.fit`?

Answer (score 5):

`steps_per_epoch` tells the network how many batches to include in an epoch.

By definition, an `epoch` is considered complete when the dataset has been run through the model once in its entirety. With other words, it means that all training samples have been run through the model. (For further discussion, let us assume that the size of the training examples is 'm').

Also by definition, we know that `batch size' is between [1, m].

Below is what [TensorFlow page](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate) says about `steps_per_epoch`

> If you want to run training only on a specific number of batches from this Dataset, you can pass the steps_per_epoch argument, which specifies how many training steps the model should run using this Dataset before moving on to the next epoch.

Now suppose that your training_size, `m = 128` and batch_size, `b = 16`, which means that your data is grouped into 8 batches. According to the above quote, the maximum value you can assign to `steps_per_epoch` is 8, as computed in [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49923476/8314782) by @Ioannis Nasios.

However, it is not necessary that you set the value to 8 only (as in our example). You can choose any value between 1 and 8. You just need to be aware that the training will be performed only with this number of batches.

The reason for the jumpy error values could be the size of your batch, as correctly mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49924566/8314782) by @Chris Farr.

[Training & evaluation from tf.data Datasets](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate#training_evaluation_from_tfdata_datasets)

> If you do this, the dataset is not reset at the end of each epoch, instead we just keep drawing the next batches. The dataset will eventually run out of data (unless it is an infinitely-looping dataset).

The advantage of a low value for `steps_per_epoch` is that different epochs are trained with different data sets (a kind of regularization). However, if you have a limited training size, using only a subset of stacks would not be what we want. It is a decision one has to make.

Answer (score 1):

The Steps per epoch denote the number of batches to be selected for one epoch.
If 500 steps are selected then the network will train for 500 batches to complete one epoch.
If we select the large number of epochs it can be computational

Comment: This does not answer the question and should be deleted or placed as a comment.