# Why does Keras run only 5 epochs out of 25?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have uninstalled Keras and Tensorflow and installed them both using

```
 pip install tensorflow == 2.6


 pip install keras == 2.6
```

But even after, I still have this strange thing that it's only 5 epochs that are running:

[image]

I cannot track when this situation occurred, but it used to run all of the epochs.
Here is my code:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1.0/255.)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1.0/255.)

train_generator = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(base_dir,
                                                    batch_size=20,
                                                    label_mode='categorical',
                                                    validation_split = 0.2,
                                                    subset='training',
                                                    seed=123,
                                                    image_size=(200, 200))

validation_generator = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(base_dir,
                                                        batch_size=20,
                                                        label_mode='categorical',
                                                        validation_split = 0.2,
                                                        subset='validation',
                                                        seed=123,
                                                        image_size=(200, 200))
model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(200, 200, 3)),
    MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(256, activation='relu'),
    Dense(4, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer='Adam',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy']
)

history = model.fit(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch = 25,   
    epochs = 25,
    validation_data = validation_generator,
    validation_steps = 25,    
    verbose = 1
)

plot_loss(history)
```

I also use

```
import logging
logging.getLogger("tensorflow").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

Please direct me.

Comment: 5 out of 10 or 5 out of 25?

Comment: Sorry, my brain is melting. Out of 25. But I also have an InceptionV3 model that has 50 epochs and still running 5.

Comment: You do not need to specify steps per epoch in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the `steps_per_epoch = 25` and the `steps_per_epoch = 25` with just `batch_size = 25`.

Comment: Wow, it worked perfectly fine. But could you please tell me what was the problem with steps_per_epoch? Why I could use it freely in the previous used version and it was pretty fine?

Comment: @ElizabethGrant Maybe this will help? [How to set batch_size, steps_per epoch, and validation steps?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/29719/how-to-set-batch-size-steps-per-epoch-and-validation-steps)

Comment: Thank you so much, I've checked it and I've read the documentation few times, but I still don't understand what the problem is since everything works fine without steps_per_epoch, but with mentioning it, it cuts the amount of epochs

Comment: @ElizabethGrant *"Traditionally, the steps per epoch is calculated as `train_length // batch_size`, since this will use all of the data points, one batch size worth at a time. "* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49922252/choosing-number-of-steps-per-epoch