# sentence transformer use of evaluator

Tags: python, nlp, sentence-transformers

I came across [this script](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/blob/master/examples/training/sts/training_stsbenchmark_continue_training.py) which is second link on [this page](https://www.sbert.net/examples/training/sts/README.html)  and [this explanation](https://www.sbert.net/docs/package_reference/SentenceTransformer.html)
I am using `all-mpnet-base-v2` ([link](https://huggingface.co/sentence-transformers/all-mpnet-base-v2)) and I am using my custom data

I am having hard time understanding use of

```
evaluator = EmbeddingSimilarityEvaluator.from_input_examples(
    dev_samples, name='sts-dev')
```

The documentation says:

> evaluator – An evaluator (sentence_transformers.evaluation) evaluates the model performance during training on held-out dev data. It is used to determine the best model that is saved to disc.

But in this case, as we are fine tuning on our own examples, `train_dataloader`has `train_samples` which has our model sentences and scores.

**Q1. How is `train_samples` different than `dev_samples`?**

**Q2a: If the model is going to print performance against `dev_samples` then how is it going to help "*to determine the best model that is saved to disc*"?**

**Q2b: Are we required to run `dev_samples` against the model saved on the disc and then compare scores?**

**Q3. If my goal is to take a single model and then fine tune it, is it okay to skip parameters `evaluator` and `evaluation_steps`?**

**Q4. How to determine total steps in the model? Do I need to set `evaluation_steps`?**

---

#### Updated

I followed the answer provided by Kyle and have below follow up questions

In the `fit` method I used the `evaluator` and below data was written to a file
[image]

**Q5. which metric is used to select the best epoch? is it `cosine_pearson`?**

**Q6: why steps are `-1` in the above output?**

**Q7a: how to find steps based upon size of my data, batch size etc.**

Currently i have kept them to 1000. But not sure if that it is too much. I am running for 10 epochs, i have 2509 examples in the training data and batch size is 64.

**Q7b: are my steps going to be 2509/64?** if yes then 1000 seems to be too high number

Comment: Which model is this? What dataset are you predicting on? What's your transformers version?

Comment: I have added those details. thanks

Comment: creating additional bounty to reward the current answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Question 1

> How is `train_samples` different from `dev_samples` in the context of the `EmbeddingSimilarityEvaluator`?

One needs to have a "held-out" split of data to be used for evaluation during training to avoid over-fitting. This "held-out" set is commonly referred to as the "development set" as it is the set of data that is used during *development* of the model/system. A pedagogical analogy can be drawn between a traditional education curriculum and that of training deep learning models: if one were to give students all the questions for a given topic, and then use the same subset of questions for evaluation, then eventually (most) students will learn to memorise the set of answers they repeatedly see while practicing, instead of learning the procedures to solve the questions in general. So if you are using your own custom data, make sure that a subset of that data is [allocated to](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/blob/master/examples/training/sts/training_stsbenchmark_continue_training.py#L57) `dev_samples` in addition to `train_samples` and `test_samples`. Alternatively, if your own data is scarce, you can use the original training data to supplement your own training, development and test sets. The "test set" is the one that [is only used after training](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/blob/master/examples/training/sts/training_stsbenchmark_continue_training.py#L96) has completed to determine the final performance of the model (i.e. all samples in the test set (ideally) haven't been seen before).

#### Question 2

> How is the model going to determine the best model that is saved to disc? Are we required to run `dev_samples` against the model saved on the disc and then compare scores?

The previous answer alludes to how this will work, but in brief, once the `evaluator` [has been instantiated](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/blob/master/examples/training/sts/training_stsbenchmark_continue_training.py#L72), it will [measure the correlation](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/blob/master/sentence_transformers/evaluation/EmbeddingSimilarityEvaluator.py#L66) against the gold labels and then [return the similarity score](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/blob/master/sentence_transformers/evaluation/EmbeddingSimilarityEvaluator.py#L128) (depending on what `main_similarity` was [initially set](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/blob/master/sentence_transformers/evaluation/EmbeddingSimilarityEvaluator.py#L23)). If the produced embeddings (based on the development set) offer a higher correlation with their gold labels, and therefore, a [higher score overall](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/blob/master/sentence_transformers/SentenceTransformer.py#L782), then this "better" model is saved to disk. Hence, there is no need for you to "run `dev_samples` against the model saved on the disc and then compare scores", this process happens automatically provided everything has been set up appropriately.

#### Question 3

> If my goal is to take a single model and then fine tune it, is it okay to skip parameters `evaluator` and `evaluation_steps`?

Based on the above answers, you can understand why you cannot "skip the `evaluator` and `evaluation_steps`". The `evaluator` is an integral part of "fine-tuning" (i.e. training) the model.

#### Question 4

> How to determine the total number of steps for the model? I need to set `evaluation_steps`.

The `evaluation_steps` parameter sets the number of training steps that [must occur](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/blob/master/sentence_transformers/SentenceTransformer.py#L736) before the model is evaluated using the `evaluator`. If the authors have set this to 1000, then leave it as is unless you notice problems with training. Alternatively, experiment with either increasing of decreasing it and select a value that works best for training.

### Follow-Up Questions

#### Question 5

> Which metric is used to select the best epoch? Is it `cosine_pearson`?

[By default](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/blob/master/sentence_transformers/evaluation/EmbeddingSimilarityEvaluator.py#L129), the maximum of the Cosine Spearman, Manhattan Spearman, Euclidean Spearman and Dot Product Spearman is used.

#### Question 6

> Why are steps `-1` in the output?

The `-1` lets the user know that the evaluator was called after all training steps occurred for a particular epoch.

If the `steps_per_epoch` was not set when calling the `model.fit()`, it [defaults to](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/blob/master/sentence_transformers/SentenceTransformer.py#L605) `None` which [sets](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/blob/master/sentence_transformers/SentenceTransformer.py#L656) the number of `steps_per_epoch` to the size of the `train_dataloader` which is passed to `train_objectives` when `model.fit()` is initially called, i.e.:

```py
model.fit(train_objectives=[(train_dataloader, train_loss)],
          ...)
```

In your case, `train_samples` is 2,509 and `train_batch_size` is 64, so the size of `train_dataloader`, and therefore `steps_per_epoch`, will be 39.

If the `steps_per_epoch`, is less than the `evaluation_steps`, then the number of [training steps](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/blob/master/sentence_transformers/SentenceTransformer.py#L736) won't reach or exceed `evaluation_steps` and so additional calls to `_eval_during_training` on line [737](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/blob/master/sentence_transformers/SentenceTransformer.py#L737) won't occur. This isn't a problem as the evaluation is forced to call at the end of each epoch anyway based on line [747](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/blob/master/sentence_transformers/SentenceTransformer.py#L747).

#### Question 7

> How do I find the number of `evaluation_steps` based on the size of my training data (2,509 samples) and batch size (64)? Is 1000 too high?

The `evaluation_steps` is available to tell the model during the training process whether it should prematurely run an evaluation using the `evaluator` part-way through an epoch. Otherwise, the evaluation is forced to run at the end of the epoch after `steps_per_epoch` have completed.

Based on the numbers you provided, you could, for example, set `evaluation_steps` to 20 to get an evaluation to run approx. half-way through an epoch (assuming an epoch is 39 `training_steps`). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49924566/20087266) and its question for more info. on batch size vs. epochs vs. steps per epoch.

Comment: could you provide your views on update1? thanks for the answer!

Comment: @user2543622 Follow-up questions have been answered

Comment: @alvas Thank you, keep up the good work on here

Comment: Kyle - would like to know more about what you do and your background- If you dont mind. Really impressed with your answers

Comment: @user2543622 Appreciate the extra bounty, thank you. I'm currently researching new performant methods for Natural Language Inference as part of my PhD candidature. My background is in electronics engineering, mainly embedded systems. Thanks, I try to keep answers high-quality as I know that poor explanations can end up being more confusing for readers