# How can I get rid of NaN on the predictions and loss? LSTM with Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I'm currently learning about forecasting time series using a very simple dataset with 8 columns (All numbers) with a total of 795 samples for training and 89 for testing (No NaN values)

The data has been normalized using:

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(dataset_to_train)
```

Later, after separating the target from the features, I used Keras to create a LSTM (x_train is scaled_data without the target column):

```
lstm_net = Sequential()
lstm_net.add(LSTM(20, input_shape=(x_train.shape[1],1), return_sequences=True))
lstm_net.add(LSTM(10,return_sequences=False))
lstm_net.add(Dense(5))
lstm_net.add(Dense(1))
```

And for the compiling (Have tried other compilers like adam or rmsprop with no change at all):

```
lstm_net.compile(optimizer = 'sgd', loss = 'mean_squared_error', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

And for the fitting:

```
lstm_net.fit(x_train,y_train, epochs=50 , batch_size=1)
```

It shows this:

```
Epoch 30/50
795/795 [==============================] - 2s 2ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0474
```

Which has very low accuracy and nan loss all the time.

To get the final predictions:

```
predictions = lstm_net.predict(x_test)
print(predictions)
```

And it prints a whole array of [nan]

Any advice on how can I try to solve this? Have tried everything I have found on other posts or forums and most people specify it might be due to a gradient problem, and even tried different scalers with no results so I'm lost.

Comment: try predicting before fitting

Comment: Is it not  supposed to train it before using it? For some reason it works, but I still don't understand how or why (Thanks for the answer by the way)

Comment: yes, it should work but predicting wrong values. Are there nan values within predictions ?

Comment: If I train it, only returns nan values. Otherwise returns numbers but all extremely similar

Comment: Can you post a sample of the data? This is most likely an issue with what is fed into the network

Comment: Following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37232782/nan-loss-when-training-regression-network) as reference might helpful to resolve this issue or try by changing the optimizer from 'sgd' to 'adam'.

Comment: *@Javier Romero*: really, Adaptive Moment Estimation(Adam) will help as of your problem's description in comments

Comment: BTW, if your model is not a classification - metric 'accuracy' is insufficient, use *metrics=keras.metrics.mean_absolute_error* for regression