# Why my regression model gives 0 to loss and metric?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

```
xss=StandardScaler()
yss=StandardScaler()

 dataset=pd.read_csv('primes.csv')
 x_train=dataset["x"]
 x_train=x_train[0:5400]
 y_train=dataset["y"]
 y_train=y_train[0:5400]
 x_test=dataset["x"]
 x_test=x_test[5400:]
 y_test=dataset["y"]
 y_test=y_test[5400:]
 x_train=[x_train]
 y_train=[y_train]
 x_train=xss.fit_transform(x_train)
 y_train=yss.fit_transform(y_train)
 x_train = np.asarray(x_train).astype('float32')
 y_train = np.asarray(y_train).astype('float32')



 model=Sequential()
 model.add(Dense(1024,activation="relu"))
 model.add(Dropout(0.01))
 model.add(Dense(128,activation="relu"))
 model.add(Dropout(0.01))
 model.add(Dense(24,activation="relu"))
 model.add(Dense(1,activation="linear"))
 optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1.5e-2,0.5)
 model.compile(optimizer = optimizer, loss = 'mse', metrics = ['mean_absolute_error'])
 model.fit(x_train,y_train,epochs=10,batch_size=128)
```

I want my output to be between 0 to 100000 but it only outputs 0 at loss and metric after so many iterations.

> Epoch 1/10
> 1/1 [==============================] - 1s 582ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0000e+00
> Epoch 2/10
> 1/1 [==============================] - 0s 30ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0000e+00
> Epoch 3/10
> 1/1 [==============================] - 0s 25ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0000e+00
> Epoch 4/10
> 1/1 [==============================] - 0s 28ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0000e+00
> Epoch 5/10
> 1/1 [==============================] - 0s 26ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0000e+00
> Epoch 6/10
> 1/1 [==============================] - 0s 26ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0000e+00
> Epoch 7/10
> 1/1 [==============================] - 0s 28ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0000e+00
> Epoch 8/10
> 1/1 [==============================] - 0s 27ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0000e+00
> Epoch 9/10
> 1/1 [==============================] - 0s 28ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0000e+00
> Epoch 10/10
> 1/1 [==============================] - 0s 27ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0000e+00

[CSV file that I am using](https://github.com/landingburn/Prime/blob/main/primes.csv)

Comment: What is the shape of your labels?

Comment: You shouldn't be using a softmax in your last layer for regression. Softmax outputs probabilities in range `[0, 1]`.

Comment: I actually don't have a label but numbers, you can take a look at the csv attachment

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO! It would be better if  you added more information in your question like output logs.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the activation function of the last layer to "linear". Since you are trying to perform regression "linear" activation function is suitable. "softmax" is used to do classification as @Nikhil Kumar has mentioned.

Comment: It is giving nan on the loss and metric now, do you have any idea about that?

Comment: Can you post a link to your dataset and complete code so that I can try to replicate the issue?

Comment: Just did, you can take a look.

Comment: I think the issue might be resulting from the fact that I am not regulating the data but i figured it would defeat the whole purpose.

Comment: Here is another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37232782/nan-loss-when-training-regression-network) about the same issue. Other possible alterations to the code are discussed here.

Comment: I tried and updated the code, however, still the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use regularization on your data (scale it to values between 0-1). Your model is probably too big (over 15M parameters) for such data. Why do you fitting 5400 data points at once? I don't think that is what you meant to do. If you want to find correlation between x and y, you need to divide your dataset into batches of (x(1), y(1)) not (x(5400), y(5400)).

Comment: What regularization method (to not detroy the whole idea) would you reccomend? And how should I divide my dataset?

Comment: You need to know what is the maximum value of data you are trying to predict and then divide whole dataset by this value so you get values between 0 and 1. Check some tf tutorials so you would understand how to create datasets.

Comment: Updated the code, what do you think is the problem now?