# Why is the output of my neural network NaN?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, reinforcement-learning

I have created this neural network:

```
obs_shape = (288, 512, 3)
num_actions = 2

input = layers.Input(shape=obs_shape)
x = layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu')(input)
x = layers.MaxPool2D((2, 2))(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.MaxPool2D((2, 2))(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.MaxPool2D((2, 2))(x)
x = layers.Flatten()(x)
x = layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')(x)
actions = layers.Dense(num_actions, activation='softmax')(x)
actor = keras.Model(input, actions, name="actor")
```

My input is a rescaled image which has values between 0 and 1.
In my program I use this network for an implementation of an Actor-Critic Reinforcement Learning method and after two episodes when I use:

```
# actor is the aforementioned network
# observation is the aforementioned kind of image
actor.predict(observation)
```

I get an array containing NaN values.
How can I fix this problem? What affects this? The learning rate of my optimizer (I use RMSprop)? The custom computation of the gradients?

Comment: Try to print intermediate layer output.

Comment: possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37232782/nan-loss-when-training-regression-network